# Why is my PS3's internet so slow compared to my computer?

Tags: ps3, networking

OK so I ran a [speed test](http://speedtest.net) on my computer and my PS3. The results were stunning!

- Computer: 14.12 Mbps
- PS3: 0.89 Mbps

When I ran this test I disconnected all devices except for the one that was running the test.

Is the PS3's network card just bad, is it the browsers slow Flash rendering, or the browser itself?

Comment: The ps3 has some weird stuff going with it, I've definitely noticed that it takes longer to render a page on my ps3 than it does on my net-book. I believe its because of the architecture of the device needed by the cell processor.

Comment: @jblaske: Same here. I really wish they would just use Google Chrome as their browser. I could have done this if they didn't take out support for Linux.

Comment: Just to make sure, when you say Mbps, you do mean MegaBITS per second?

Comment: Slow flash rendering would not explain such an excessive decrease in speed - is your PC also running wirelessly? (PS. this would fit better at superuser.com)

Comment: How are your PC and PS3 connected to the network (i.e. wirelessly or via ethernet)?

Comment: @Powerlord: Yes I do mean BITS not bytes. @splattered: Wirelessly.

Comment: Lucas have you considered using power over ethernet? i.e. http://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-TL-PA211KIT-200Mbps-Powerline-Ethernet/dp/B004INVKP4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1319790987&sr=8-1 I've got this for my PS3 and it solves the overcrowded wifi networks problem. You can plug the other end into your wifi router

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend using a wired connection with the ps3, especially if you live in a densely populated neighborhood. The reason I say this is not even about speed, but about reliabilty.

The ps3 wireless is 802.11g, which operates at roughly the same frequency as microwave ovens, and a lot of other stuff. If you're just browsing from a PC, you might not even notice a momentary network glitch, but when you get dropped out of an on-line game session and lose a bucketful of XP, you will notice.

Comment: I would love to be able to connect it via hardwire but the closest cable hook ups are on the other side of my house.

Comment: Best Buy now offers pairs of Powerline Network connections that might help you. Connect one to an outlet with your router and the other in an outlet in the room with your system. Supposedly your house can support any number of these devices at 85Mbps.

Comment: @Lucas Or just get a really long ethernet cable, it'd be much cheaper..

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. My PS3 was connected wirelessly to my network.  The base station was in my office, at the other end of the house. I would get abysmally low bandwidth when streaming internally or from the internet.

My solution was to move my base station into the entertainment center and connect the PS3 to it via ethernet.  Ever since, I've not noticed any bandwidth problems. Everything downloads lickity-split.

Comment: I can't do this since I have no cable hookups in the room where my PS3 is. Do you know of another possible solution?

Comment: You could test by temporarily moving your PS3/tv into a room where you can hook it via ethernet.  It would be a pain, but at least you'd know if it fixes the problem.  You could then call your ISP to come and install a physical jack in your gaming room so you could move your router.

Comment: It's really easy to run an ethernet cable through the roof and down the inside of the wall. Definitely no special skills or handyman experience required. Did it when I was a kid (prior to wireless).

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple fix... Go to "network settings", go to the bottom of the list where it says "media server connection" and disable it. Now run a test. My speeds when from around 1mg down to 9.

Answer (score 1):

PS3 is flakey. I have a slim model now, but i also had one of the launch PS3s until it yellow lighted on me. Previously i was getting great speeds but now not so much.

Previous setup had great speed running on a wireless Linksys WRT54G
Solid almost 6mbs down connection. which is what i was paying for at the time.

Eventually I went to a Trendnet TEW-652BRP N draft 2, and my wifi speeds were terribad.

So i set up a client bridge using the WRT54G and voila my speeds were 10x faster than using the PS3 wireless connection, even though it was still wireless, having the PS3 plugged into a secondary router using it as a wifi adapter seriously took it from about 0.5mbps to 5mbps. You may wonder why i did it this way, well not only did i plug the PS3 in wired, i also plugged my xbox 360 and Panasonic Viera Cast TV all to the secondary router while the primary router was in the office connected to the desktop and a network share(HDD). No need to buy the $80 M$ wifi adapter for the xbox360.

Since then i upgraded to a 16mbps/7mbps service and relocated the primary router to the living room since most of the activity happens there, and decided to just use a wireless N adapter on my desktop. I also upgraded to a Cisco/Linksys E3000.

However my PS3 is only getting 2.7mbps down on average wired, even though my PCs are getting 11-15 mbps wireless. Oddly the PS3 is getting consistent 4.3 Mbps up and occasionally can hit 8Mbps down. Still a far cry from the low end 11 that my wireless PCs get.

edit. HA! Just ran another speed test using the Internet Connection Test in the XMB
19.3 Mbps down
2.2 Mbps up

I didn't change a thing.

Maybe the PS3 connection test software is just whack.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue that only affects its internet browser. I stream HD video from my computer wirelessly to my PS3 and everything goes really smooth.

Comment: No it's actually affecting gameplay as well.

Comment: I've also noticed abysmal speeds from ps store, as well as wifi file transfer of music/video

Comment: The reason it don't affect streaming from your pc, is that is a local network, not Internet PSN servers. Local speed is much higher. It's not just the browser on your ps3 that is affected. It is anything you do through PSN (ps3 internet) the speed test on your PSN/PS3 Internet test affects anything you do on your ps3 over PSN (gaming, downloads, browsing under your ID etc).

Answer (score 0):

Copied and pasted my answer from [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/77704/8967):

If you are having device-specific issues, it's most likely your router.  I know that DD-wrt firmware routers have special options that optimize gaming performance.  I would take a look at this article:

[Optimizing your PS3 network connection](http://gamer.blorge.com/2009/02/07/optimizing-your-playstation-3-network-connection/)

It goes over the general tweaks you can do to increase the performance of your PS3 (for both wired and wireless connections).

Some mentioned tweaks / solutions:

- Enable UPnP.  This should tell your router what ports to forward.  If this is not enabled, you can manually forward the ports after giving your PS3 a static IP.  The ports are TCP ports 80, 443, 5223 and UDP ports 3658, and 3478-3479.
- Setting up your PS3 in a DMZ (demilitarized zone) could help.  How-to is mentioned in the article.
- Update the firmware on your router.  Personally, I think dd-wrt is awesome, so if your router supports it, I'd recommend you go with that.

Aside from that, you might be better off getting a new router that can deal with the different level of traffic a console creates.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PS3 Network settings. I'm using TrendNet's powerline adapters to run two PS3's. It's better than wireless.

The other day I did a Windows update and after restart I could not connect to either. I thought it was Java proble (however I had recently installed the latest). I also had the most recent PMS version (1.80). In the end I believe recsetting my adapters helped but the point to all this is one PS3 was extremely slow. Video was unwatchable when before it was fine. In all my trouble the one PS3 seemed to lose it's network settings. After setting up I realized after many hour that I simply entered information incorrectly. After comparing setups I changed the one to same as the other with the exception of the IP. Now it works great.

There are many factors like java memory too and PMS settings that can help you video run better. If on wirelss, strongly suggest wired or powerline.