# Why is my wired Internet connection slow on my PS3?

Tags: ps3, networking

My ISP connection is 30 meg down and 5 up.  My PlayStation 3 is hardwired with cat5e.  All of the PlayStation Network ports are configured and forwarded on my router.

The test: Go to speakeasy with PS3 and perform test with Seattle.  This is the best glass backbone to Montana.  I am lucky if I get 4 meg download speed, the up speed is decent.  Second test, unplug PlayStation 3 and plug in MacBook Pro.  The results are that I can utilize the full bandwidth of my service from the same patch cable, wire through house and port on router.  30 down and 4.8 up.

I also removed ubuiti router and replaced with a pos netgear.  Test results did not vary and router firmwares were up to date.  Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my PS3's internet so slow compared to my computer?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6819/why-is-my-ps3s-internet-so-slow-compared-to-my-computer)

Comment: Though most of that question and answers came down to plugging in your PS3, which you have done.

Comment: The post is nothing close to a duplicate from the previous.  I did read that post.  I tried to be very detailed so I would not receive a plethora of meaningless comments.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried plugging your PS3 directly into your modem and bypassing the router, just to eliminate the router as an issue?

Comment: This thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3207179?start=0&tstart=0 suggests manually changing your network settings and using Full Duplex mode.  Worth a shot (although the OP specifically mentioned using an Airport router).   Might also try a wifi connection on the PS3 just to see how it compares.

Comment: Yes, I have tried patching straight to modem.  I would guess that if it were an equipment issue on the network side, my Macs or PCs would also see the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I am not using an Airport.  I am using a Ubiquiti router.  More commercial than retail.  As stated before I did swap out with a big box store brand with no luck.  Try WiFi???  I thought PS3 consoles were known for weak wireless cards.  I am in the low voltage industry.  Always get copper to the equipment that you most depend on.

Comment: There is evidence (from reading various forum posts) that PS3s can have issues when other devices don't, so it was worth a shot.  And yes, wifi works like a champ on my PS3 :)  I'd recommend an N router though, typically much stronger signal IME than G.   Anyway, just trying to help!

Comment: Thanks Ben.  No dice, the service is about the same.  What kind of speeds do you get with wireless?

Comment: Did you try the PS3's own network test instead of speakeasy?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the thing about data transfer and the device it's connected to. While I suggest you keep looking for a fix, the main thing about Bandwidth utilization is that even if a great quantity of data is being sent to your PS3 by your router, it's dedicated network processor can only process so much data, and Sony limits this to save on procedural resources to the highest necessary speed.

The PS3 uses a CELL processor setup with several modular CPUs, but just 256 MB of ram, so its ability to receive and process incoming data is quite limited.

I would still suggest you stick with the wired connection to limit latency.